# What are THM files in Canon SD Card

Tags: canon-550d, file

I have a Canon 550D and I have a THM for each picture that I have taken in my SD Card.

What is a THM file and what is it used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a thumbnail file. Usually it's generated when you take a video, to give you a preview image on the LCD and to store the EXIF information for exposure, focal length, etc.

You can rename it to .jpg if you want to view it on your computer.

Comment: I've been finding a bunch of these for videos I would shoot on an old Canon A640 point and shoot camera, I always thought they were metadata but you're right it's a lil jpg thumbnail. The size that shows up when I change the extension is `160x120`

Answer (score 1):

Just based on the "THM", I'd guess it's a thumbnail of the picture. I haven't looked specifically at the 550D, but in the cameras I have looked at, it was really just a small JPEG with a somewhat unusual name.

As far as what it's used for, the camera loads it when you're viewing pictures on camera. Only when/if you zoom in does it load the full-resolution version.